# Swig applying %exception directive on %extend methods

Tags: c++, exception, swig, extend

I am trying to apply an exception catch handler to a method I added to a class with the %extend directive (but with no success).

My Simple Test.h File:

```
namespace Test {
  class TestClass
  {
    int method1()
    {
      throw MyException();
    }
  }
}
```

My Swig File:

```
%module Test

%{
#include Test.h
%}

%extend Test::TestClass {
  int method2()
  {
    throw MyException();
  }
}

%exception {
  try {
    $action
  } catch (MyException& e) {
    // do something
  }
}

%include "Test.h"
```

When I compile this swig file, the wrapper for `method1` is generated with the exception handler but the wrapper for `method2` is generated without the exception handler (I also tried to all the variants of full method name declaration and alot of other attempts with no success).

Is there a way to add the `%exception` directive to extended method in Swig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the order of the `%extend` and `%exception` directives around in your interface. The order you apply them in is important which allows you to selectively include and exclude things from being modified.

Comment: Don't know how I could have missed it! In advance to your answer, do you have any swig file template that will help organize my swig files? I have like hundred of swig files, from different packages and it's difficult to manage all these small parts that causing this annoying bugs.

Comment: @or.m I try to treat this like any other C++ library - split the useful bits out and make them into the smallest possible unit of code that makes sense. Most I %include in other projects later (std_XXXX.i). A few I %import instead, but that's rare that something makes enough sense to standalone like that.